# SQL Management Studio do not recognize oracledbProvider

Tags: sql-server-2008, oracle11g, ssms, bids, odac

I am facing this problem:

I have installed Oracle Client 11g 64bits version also ODAC 11g 64bits, I have modified PATH environment, but SQL Server Management Studio do not show the OracleDBProvider, If I try to execute "Export and Import Data" Oracle provider works great.

Why is SQL Server Management Studio presenting this problem?

Any help would be appreciated

I am using Windows Server 2012 with SQL Server 2008R2 both are 64b

Comment: Because SQL Server Management Studio is a tool for managing SQL Server databases, and Oracle is not SQL Server?

Comment: Of course, but I need to install Oracle client and ODACS to work with some SQL Server Management tools for example: linked servers. So if try to create a new linked server OracleProvider is not present.

Comment: You should put that information in your question, instead of in the comments.